# OpenCV 2.4.3 Download

Tags: c++, opencv

Looking to learn OpenCV with C++, but all the tutorials I've found on youtube are with CV 2.4.3. On OpenCV's website, there is no 2.4.3 download link. Does anyone know why, or where I can find an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Learn the new 3.0 version instead? Also there's 2.4.11 on the opencv downloads page which should work just fine with your tutorials.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl I would start learning 3.0, but there aren't as many comprehensive tutorials for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloaded 2.4.11 version couple weeks ago, so I guess that's the latest stable 2x version. You should be fine learning stuff from whole 2.4 version, most of them are essentially the same, [this newspost](http://opencv.org/opencv-2-4-3-released.html) tells that 2.4.3 version was more a bug and performance update.

Offtopic, learning via Youtube videos isn't a good idea, most of the time it turns out to be more c/p then learning what are you doing, suggest you to learn how to read their on-site API documentation.

Comment: Alright, cheers mate!